# Iteration over data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a table A with column names: `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3`.

```
Var1 = c("N1", "N2", "0", "0", "N3", "N4", "0", "0")
Var2 = c("0", "A", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0", "0")
Var3 = c("0", "Yes", "No", "All", "0", "x", "y", "z")
```

I would like to obtain vectors based on Table A,  which contains values from column eg: `N2 = (Yes, No, All)`, `N4 = (x, y, z)`.
I have tried few iterations with "for loop" and "logical if" but with no success. Please, give me some hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`:

- replace the `0`s in `Var1` by `NA`
- carry forward last occurence of non `NA` values (using for example `zoo::na.locf` because `data.table::nafill` [doesnt yet work for characters](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3992)).
- filter according to `Var1`:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(Var1 = c("N1", "N2", "0", "0", "N3", "N4", "0", "0"), Var2 = c("0", "A", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0", "0"), Var3 = c("0", "Yes", "No", "All", "0", "x", "y", "z"))

# replace 0s by NA for next step
data[Var1==0,Var1:=NA]

# last occurence carried forward
data[,Var1:=zoo::na.locf(Var1)]

data[Var1=='N2',Var3]
#[1] "Yes" "No"  "All"

data[Var1=='N4',Var3]
#[1] "x" "y" "z"
```